# isNew returns false even when I have created a new session.Why is that ?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, httpsession

In the following snippet,`uSession.isNew`always returns false. Why is that ? I create a new session but the corresponding method returns `false`.

```
HttpSession uSession = request.getSession();
    if(uSession.isNew()) {System.out.println("Inside if statement---------");
        uSession.setAttribute("username", username);
        uSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("User.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

I have even tried after deleting all the localhost cookies from the browser.

Comment: Try using `HttpSession#invalidate`.

Comment: Because HttpSession exists before request.getSession() called so isNew return false. Need to check where/time httpSession created before HttpSession uSession = request.getSession();

Comment: Also, you're not creating a new sesion in this code.

Comment: getSession(false) will not return a new Session if one does not already exist. and check if session is null or not

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza new session ? You mean by passing a boolean ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Will this not automatically create a new session, if it doesn't exist ?

Comment: getSession() = getSession(true). It will return existing HttpSession if the existing httpSession created BEFORE in somewhere.

Comment: Refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9464166/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that should set the if block running !

Comment: @Loc I have not created the session anywhere else in my app

Comment: @SaplinPro: Ok. If the code block executed for the FIRST time ( first request), uSession.isNew() will return true, but for SUB-sequence requests, uSession.isNew will always return false because uSession created in the first request.

Comment: @Loc but it is returning false here

Comment: @saplingPro: You mean it return false for the FIRST request?

Comment: @Loc yes.this is what the question is all about

Comment: The reason may be your application server restore session data after stop/start. Check your WAS and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Jsp automatically creates a session. I don't know why it creates. But it does. So your jsp automatically creates a session and that's why `isNew()` returns false all the time.
The solution is to set the session to false in the JSP Page Directive. i.e.,
Use `<%@ page session="false"%`